# Spring Controller's URL request mapping not working only a blank page with a string

Tags: javascript, java, spring

Hu everyone, im'working on this project at the moment!
https://github.com/fedexu/FilmRental

I mapped the entity, and created a HelloWorldController

```
@RestController
public class helloWord {

@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleRequest() throws Exception {
    return "login";
}
```

Added in WebServiceConfig.java

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
   InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
   resolver.setPrefix("webapp/views/");
   resolver.setSuffix(".html");
   return resolver;
}
```

i create the view login.html by the way when i go
http://localhost:8080/FilmRental/login
I have a blank page with the String login (like the return String) and not the view

Comment: Have you set FilmRental as contextpath? If not just use `http://localhost:8080/login`

Comment: yes. added, i  tried with your link too but noway

Answer (score 4):

Change `@RestController` to `@Controller`. The former is used to return objects and not views

Comment: That was good, now i get "Cant' reach this page"
Im worried about theButton call

[html]<input type="button" onclick="location.href='login'" value="Staff_AreaRiservata" /> [html]

Comment: What do you mean "Im worried about the Button call..."?

Comment: after that edit i really cant undertsand why my button dont remand me in the new view!
This is the defnition of a button finded online for map the new controller
[html]<input type="button" onclick="location.href='login'"value="Staff_AreaRiservata" /> [html]

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console? I suspect there will be, but this is moving off the original question and into JavaScript domain. It might be something to do with the `location.href=login`

Comment: yo got right!
On my COnsole:
Mapped "{[/login],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.filmrental.controller.helloWord.handleRequest() throws java.lang.Exception